# Follow the links of the tab in jquery ui tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have jquery tabs like

```
<ul id="tabsList">
    <li><a href="#tab-1">Name 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-2">Name 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com/">Name 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="tab-1">content 1</div>
<div id="tab-2">content 2</div>
```

the first two tabs load the respective divs. But the third one should go to google.com, instead it does nothing. It just adds http://example.com/index.html**#ui-tabs-[object Object]**
 to the url.

I am developing a wordpress plugin and the admin page needs a tab interface. I tested this in a local server and not working

**update:**

i don't want to load google.com inside the page. It should open the webpage in new tab/window like ordinary links do.

Comment: why have a tab that opens a new window....makes no sense

Comment: @redsquare can't understand the question ? read the question well

Comment: I did read the question - you then changed it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i saw the generated source code, the

```
<li><a href="http://www.google.com/">Name 3</a></li>
```

was changed to

```
<li><a href="#ui-tabs-[object Object]">Name 3</a></li>
```

But other lists were same. I still don't know whether it is due to the problem of testing in local server.

So i tried this option. I removed the "href" attribute and added a class named "theLink" like

```
<li><a class="theLink" target="_blank">Name 3</a></li>
```

and then i added the following jquery

```
$('.theLink).attr('href', 'http://www.google.com');
```

after this it worked as i excepted. The third tab when clicked loaded google.com in a new tab

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you want it to do, but if it should open the link as a new page/replacement for the current page, the documentation explains:

> [How to...] ...follow a tab's URL instead of
>   loading its content via ajax
>
> Note that opening a tab in a new
>   window is unexpected, e.g.
>   inconsistent behaviour exposing a
>   usablity problem
>   (http://www.useit.com/alertbox/tabs.html).
>
> ```
> $('#example').tabs({
>     select: function(event, ui) {
>         var url = $.data(ui.tab, 'load.tabs');
>         if( url ) {
>             location.href = url;
>             return false;
>         }
>         return true;
>     } });
> ```

See http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#...follow_a_tab.27s_URL_instead_of_loading_its_content_via_ajax

**Note:** In JQuery > 1.9.0 use **activate** instead of select

Comment: What does "is of no use" mean? Are there errors? It simply doesn't work? Please explain.

Comment: didn't work for me either.  the ajax content still loads initially... and the tab links' hrefs get changed to ui-tabs-[object]

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem.
I solved it by giving the tab anchor that should be loaded externally a class named "followtablink". Then I modified my tabs() call to this:

```
$('.tabs').tabs({
select: function(event, ui) {
    var url = $.data(ui.tab, 'load.tabs');
    var className = ui.tab.className;

    if( className == "followtablink" ) {
        location.href = url;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}});
```

Every time a tab gets selected, it follows the link when it encounters the given class.

**Note:** In JQuery > 1.9.0 use **activate** instead of select

Comment: saw this in the api docs, but it doesn't seem to prevent the tabs from loading the content via ajax initially. any tips for that?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot since requesting content from google.com will be a cross domain call and the xhr call will fail.

Why not put an iframe inside the third content div with the src attribute pointing to google?

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/P3tr9/)

```
<ul id="tabsList">
    <li><a href="#tab-1">Name 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-2">Name 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-3">Google Tab</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="tab-1">content 1</div>
<div id="tab-2">content 2</div>
<div id="tab-3">
    <iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
</div>
```